# text figures (old style numbers) and mhchem

Tags: luatex, fontspec, oldstylenums, mhchem

How do I achieve lining figures with `mhchem` while maintaining text figures in the text (lualatex).

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage[paperwidth=70mm, paperheight=20mm, left=10pt, top=20pt]{geometry}%

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Numbers=OldStyle]{Tex Gyre Pagella}%
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Tex Gyre Pagella}%

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
Chemical formula: \ce{Al2O3}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: text figure example]

but the desired output is (and as far as I am concerned should be)

[image: desired chemical formula]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put

```
\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}}
```

inside your document. But: I have never used that package, so I don't know if there is a better way.