# uppercase and mhchem

Tags: cases, mhchem

How do I achieve a proper uppercase including chemical formulas typeset with mhchem, i.e. everything but chemical formulas are capital letters?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\RequirePackage[paperwidth=70mm, paperheight=20mm, left=10pt, top=20pt]{geometry}%

\RequirePackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase{Preparation of \ce{Mn3Ga}.}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image: incorrect example output]

which produces `MN` and `GA` instead of `Mn` and `Ga`, respectively. Please note that I do not want to use $...$ (cp. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42255/text-figures-old-style-numbers-and-mhchem)) and `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package, but the `mhchem` package and `\ce{...}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `textcase` package provides a version of uppercase that is more careful about these things

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[paperwidth=70mm, paperheight=20mm, left=10pt, top=20pt]{geometry}%

\usepackage{textcase}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\MakeTextUppercase{Preparation of \NoCaseChange{\ce{Mn3Ga}}.}
\end{document}
```