# old style numerals in mhchem equations

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, mhchem

I use the Lucida font for my documents with its old style numerals in text and its lining figures in mathmode.

But how can I get lining figures inside chemical eqautions with `mhchem`?

Here is some sample code (I compile with either `latex` or `pdflatex`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=90mm, paperheight=20mm, left=10pt, top=20pt]{geometry}%

\usepackage[romanfamily=bright-osf,stdmathdigits=true,scale=.9]{lucimatx}

\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
Chemical formula: \ce{2 H2O -> 2H2 + O2}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get
[image: Old style numerals]
This is what I want
[image: No old style numerals]

I already tried

```
{\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont \ce{2 H2O -> 2H2 + O2}}
```

But that will mess up the format if the equations get more complicated

I found a related entry with the same problem but this guy uses `luatex`: [text figures (old style numbers) and mhchem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42255/text-figures-old-style-numbers-and-mhchem)

Comment: Sorry, can you explain why that will mess up the formula once it gets more complicated? By first instinct is to rename \ce to add the fontfamily commands to it, but I'm opening the mhchem manual now.

Comment: This one compiles but ignores the font command:
\begin{align*}
  \fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont \cee{2H + O2 &->[\Delta E] 4H+ + 4e- + O2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test this, as I've not purchased the Lucidia fonts, but using the `mhchem` manual I've created:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=90mm, paperheight=20mm, left=10pt, top=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[romanfamily=bright-osf,stdmathdigits=true,scale=.9]{lucimatx}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont}
\mhchemoptions{mathfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont\text}

\begin{document}
Chemical formula: \ce{2 H2O -> 2H2 + O2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mathsf` works but it makes Sans-Serif (of course). If I switch to `\mathrm` the old style numerals also come back. `\mhchemoptions{mathfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont\mathrm}` is being ignored.

Comment: `\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont}` works good, but only in textmode

Comment: Right, you'd have to change \mhchemoptions{mathfontcommand=foo} to change what it does in mathmode. Try what I have above.

Comment: `\mhchemoptions{mathfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont}` makes all letters italic.

Comment: I found a solution `\mhchemoptions{textfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont}` and `\mhchemoptions{mathfontcommand=\fontfamily{hlh}\selectfont\text}`. Maybe there are pitfalls, but for now this seems to behave correct.

Comment: I strongly suspect that will fail if you try and use math commands, as you've just defined everything inside it to use textmode.

Answer (score 3):

mhchem uses the active font. So if you write in text-mode, you'll get oldstyle numerals, whereas in math-mode you'll get lining figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{2H2O -> 2H2 + O2} \qquad $\ce{2H2O -> 2H2 + O2}$

\end{document}
```

Output will be:

[image]